# tooltip-append-to-body=true bug

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I got the very strange bug with angular-ui bootstrap tooltips. When its attribute `tooltip-append-to-body` set to `true` on **some** pages (not all of them) it doesn't work. Every time I hover the target element angular-ui appends the element to DOM (look at the screenshot), and don't delete it on "unhover".

[image]

I will be very appreciated for any thoughts about possible reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of such a strange behavior:
on those pages when the bug happens I have the 3rd-party SVG component, which is using `foreignObject`. This `foreignObject` hosts html with the `body` tag in it...